# Store user uploads on heroku temporarily

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I am deploying a Node/Next Application to Heroku that handles user file uploads, particularly audio / video files. My project root folder has a folder called Files, that handles file uploads. I am using multer for file uploads and the uploads are being stored locally in my desired folder. When I push the code to heroku, will I be able to store these files temporarily on the folder of my choice (in my case the files folder which exists in the root of my project). I don't care if the files are deleted each restart, I just want to be able to use the files for processing via a python script.

I have not yet tried it, I just want an answer to my question